# Javascript callback function doesn't modify array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, scope

I am trying to create a `to-do list page`, and I read the items from an `mongodb database`, when I `console.log(item)` **inside** the `callback function`, it prints each item.

But when I `console.log(items)` **outside** the find function, it shows up empty, and as a result, I can't get to display any items. Why is the items array empty?

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var items = [];
    Item.find({}, function(err, results) {
        results.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            items.push(item);
        });
    });
    console.log(items);
    res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItem: items });
});
```

Comment: What is `Item` ? Are you sure that `Item.find()` is not asynchronous and the empty outside console output is at the end of all logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Issue

This is happening because `Item.find()` is asynchronous and doesn't push anything into `items` yet before your `console.log(items)` or `res.render()` runs

#### Solution

- Move your `res.render()` into the `Item.find()` callback function
- Use [`Async/Await`](https://javascript.info/async-await)

With Callback

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var items = [];
    Item.find({}, function(err, results) {
        results.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            items.push(item);
        });
        console.log(items);
       res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItem: items });
    });
    
});
```

With Async/Awaits

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    var items = [];
    const results = await Item.find()
    results.forEach(function(item) {
       console.log(item);
       items.push(item);
    });
    console.log(items);
    res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItem: items });
});
```